# How do I align bottom element above (not overlay) top element using css without changing the current HTML structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I want to align the bottom element in an HTML file on top of the parent element, I do not want to overlay it, I literally want the bottom element to be on top of the top element:

Example:
HTML:

```
<div class="top-container"></div>
<div class="bottom-container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

.bottom-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Current Output:

[image]

Expected output: I want the red box to be above the green box.

Comment: `display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse;` on the parent of those nodes. But really... why not just change the HTML?

Comment: Thank you for your solution @StackSlave, the reason why I can't interchange the HTML is because I am actually trying to achieve this functionality on an angular application. I need to have the bottom div above the top div only if a configuration is set to true.

I will be using ngClass to check if the config is true and I will apply your solution in a parent div.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap the two elements in a div, if they are not already wrapped, then in the container element, `display: flex; flex-direction:column-reverse;`... if there's really no container element, your best bet is `position: relative` on the bottom element and `bottom: 400px`. They won't switch spots, but the red one will be ontop of the green one.